# Browser redirect back issue on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, symfony

I have a website written on Symfony2. It works fine, but on IPhones > 4 and IPads > 2 it behaves strangely.

When I try to go to login page, it firstly loading login page and then redirects back to main page after a few seconds. On desktop and other devices it works good.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: yep and chrome too. In Opera mini all fine